# Why is Merge Sort Performance LINEAR?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm working on comparing sorting algorithms in Python. I've implemented the algorithms and a testing function that evaluates each algorithm on various input sizes, up to a very large maximum, in the hundreds of thousands. The execution times are saved for plotting later. As expected, Selection Sort exhibits a quadratic behavior, and its graph reflects that. However, I'm encountering an issue with Merge Sort – its graph appears linear instead of the expected nlogn behavior!!

This is my implementation of Merge Sort:

```
def merge_sort(A):
    merge_sort_aux(A, 0, len(A) - 1)

# Merge Sort Helper Function
# (Recursive)
def merge_sort_aux(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = (p + r) // 2  # Integer division
        merge_sort_aux(A, p, q)
        merge_sort_aux(A, q + 1, r)
        merge(A, p, q, r)

def merge(A, p, q, r):
    # Calculate the sizes of the two sublists
    n1 = q - p + 1
    n2 = r - q

    # Create two NumPy arrays initially initialized to 0 
    # They are of type float to support sentinels
    L = np.zeros(n1 + 1, dtype=float)
    R = np.zeros(n2 + 1, dtype=float)

    # Copy data into NumPy arrays
    L[:n1] = [A[p + i] for i in range(n1)]
    R[:n2] = [A[q + 1 + j] for j in range(n2)]

    # Sentinels
    L[n1] = np.inf
    R[n2] = np.inf

    i = j = 0

    for k in range(p, r + 1):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1  # Increment the index of the left sublist to preserve the loop invariant
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1  # Increment the index of the right sublist
```

This is my function that I use to run the tests

```
def test_algo(algo_function, maxRange=TEST_MAX_DIMENSION, minRange=2, step=TEST_STEP):
    """
    Test the execution time of the given algorithm function for various input sizes.

    Parameters:
    - algo_function: The algorithm function to be tested.
    - maxRange: The maximum input size to be tested.
    - minRange: The minimum input size to start the testing.
    - step: The step size between different input sizes.

    Returns:
    - results: A dictionary to store the execution times for each input size.
    """

    results = {}  # Dictionary to store execution times for each input size

    for i in range(minRange, maxRange, step):
        A = random_list(i)  # Assuming you have a function 'random_list' generating a list of size i
        start = timer()
        algo_function(A)
        end = timer()
        results[i] = end - start

    return results
```

[image: Merge Sort perfromance]

Any suggestions or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have tested up to a list 3 million values
[image]

Comment: Selection sort's execution time should be ***quadratic***, not exponential.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, you are right

Comment: What is `timer()`? I'm more used to e.g. `time.perf_counter()`.

Comment: If I understand your question, you're surprised because the time of execution of merge sort appears to be `constant x n` but you expected it to be `constant x n x log(n)`. But actually `log(n)` is a function that increases very slowly (for instance log(1000) = 10 and log(10000) = 13 and log(100000) = 17 and log(1000000) = 20). So it's a bit hard to notice the influence of log on a plot when you don't know the constant factor.

Comment: @9769953    "  from timeit import default_timer as timer "  my teacher advised us to do this, but I can give you what you recommend, thanks

Comment: Note when you post python code on stackoverflow (or any place else) I recommend you keep the `import` lines in the code, otherwise the readers can only guess and cannot reproduce your issue. So you should put `import numpy as np` and `from timeit import default_timer as timer` at the top of the code in your question if that is what you used.

Comment: You test fewer than 20,000 elements. That's simply too little to discern big-O behavior.

Comment: @Stef Thank you! In fact I imagined that the problem was simply visualization. Do you have any advice on settings that can help me enhance the graph?

Comment: @NiccolòCaselli Yes, test with bigger values :)

Comment: I wonder if the creation of zeroed arrays and copying of the data wouldn't take the overhand, and then slow things down linearly.

Comment: @Stef Thanks for the advice! First time with Python. I'm the classic javascript evil guy :)

Comment: @9769953 I guess this is realistic. And it's also why perhaps an in-place sorting algorithm like Quicksort is preferable

Comment: @NiccolòCaselli - python is a bad language to use for benchmarking algorithms due to it's being so slow compared to compiled programs.  A basic merge sort of 16 million integers compiled from C or C++ takes less than 2 seconds, even on my older cpus going back to Intel 3770K.

Comment: @rcgldr I am aware of this. to do the tests with 3 million elements my computer (Silicon m2) took 12 minutes! But I have to do these experiments for university :(

Comment: @Stef Sorry if I bother you again. I tested up to a list of 3 million values as you can see in the EDIT. But I'm still not sure of the plot. Do you think I can say that the trend is nlogn (I have to do a report for the university)? Thanks again

Comment: @NiccolòCaselli log(2) = 1, log(3000000) = 21. I suggest plotting the theoretical curves of the two functions f(n) = n log(n) / w and g(n) = 20 n / w in addition to the curve you got with your timings, where w = 60000000 / 24 is apparently the speed of your computer in operations per seconds. (The value of w is not important at all, but what is important is that f and g use the same w) Then write a short paragraph analysing the three curves, concluding either that the trend is f(n) or that it's not possibly to distinguish f(n) from g(n) for n up to 3000000.

Comment: @NiccolòCaselli It's perfectly okay to conclude that you can't distinguish 20 n from n log(n). In any case, the main observation is that both 20 n and n log(n) are much much smaller than n^2 so merge sort is really much much faster than selection sort.

Comment: A more efficient merge sort may help. A one time copy of the original array in merge_sort (B=A)  would eliminate the need for merge to create arrays, but sentinels would not be used. A [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) would be a bit faster than top down. I suggest changing `r` to be the end of array, so that the call would be `merge_sort_aux(A, B, 0, len(A))` .

Comment: Have you tested the result of your merge sort to make sure it's really properly sorting and doesn't have a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that merge sort has linear growth, it's that O(n log n) and O(n) are very hard to distinguish visually over bounded ranges. Unless the results are scaled to account for the dominant trend effect and plotted jointly, as below, the human eye doesn't notice small amounts of curvature.

[image: x log(x) and 7.15 * x - 370 plotted jointly]

Even using statistical tools such as linear regression, a straight line fitted to O(n log n) data will yield a very high value for R<sup>2</sup>, a measure of how much of the variation in the vertical axis is explained by the value along the horizontal axis.

We generally don't know how to scale the linear or `n log n` values to be able to plot them side by side, but once you accept the idea of scaling there's a simple alternative. You can scale the results of your experiments using division by candidate complexities, such as `n`, `n log n`, `n**2`, etc., and plot the scaled result against `n` (or `log n` if the range is large). If the generated plot

- increases over `n` => the conjectured complexity is too low;
- decreases over `n` => the conjecture is too high;
- converges towards a constant => correct complexity has been identified.

To see that this works even when lower order terms are involved in the actual complexity, consider the following example where `t(n) = c1 * n**2 + c2 * n + c3` with unknown constants `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`. If we incorrectly scale by `n`, we get

```
t(n) / n = (c1 * n**2 / n) + (c2 * n / n) + (c3 / n)
         = c1 * n + c2 + (c3 / n)
```

which increases as `n` does. If we overdo it scaling by `n**3`, we get:

```
t(n) / n**3 = (c1 * n**2 / n**3) + (c2 * n / n**3) + (c3 / n**3)
            = (c1 / n) + (c2 / n**2) + (c3 / n**3)
```

which will asymptotically converge to zero. When we scale by the Goldilocks complexity `n**2`:

```
t(n) / n**2 = (c1 * n**2 / n**2) + (c2 * n / n**2) + (c3 / n**2)
            = c1 + (c2 / n) + (c3 / n**2)
```

the lower order terms rapidly converge to zero, and the scaled times will converge towards `c1`.

I used this approach in a paper published in 2018 ([DOI: 10.1002/qre.2424](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qre.2424)) to show that the rate of growth for optimal solutions (or best identified feasible solutions when optimal couldn't be determined) was greater than O(k<sup>2</sup>) but less than O(k<sup>3</sup>):

[image: plot of performance measure / k**3]

Comment: In this case, it would be simpler to divide the running time by `n`. For large enough arrays, the running time would be greater than O(n log(n)) due to exceeding cache size.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an mistake at your mergeSort func. where you created NumPy arrays for the left and right subarrays. this is extra and unnecessary step imo.

try this

```py
def mergeSort(A, p, q, r):
    n1 = q - p + 1
    n2 = r - q


    L = A[p:p + n1]
    R = A[q + 1:q + 1 + n2]

    i = j = 0
    k = p  

    while i < n1 and j < n2:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < n1:
        A[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < n2:
        A[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
```